# New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability

Tags: ios, swift

I received email from apple in the below

**ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - New apps that use UIWebView are no longer accepted. Instead, use WKWebView for improved security and reliability. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview).**

I tried this command

/Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives//app name/carchive

**the results :**

Binary file Products/Applications/app name/Frameworks/TwitterKit.framework/TwitterKit matches
Binary file dSYMs/app name.dSYM/Contents/Resources/DWARF/app name matches

**and tried**

grep -r UIWebView Pods/

**the results :**

Pods//AppAuth/README.md:for the auth request. `UIWebView` and `WKWebView` are explicitly *not*
Binary file Pods//TwitterKit/iOS/TwitterKit.framework/TwitterKit matches
Pods//TwitterKit/iOS/TwitterKit.framework/Headers/TWTRTweet.h: *  Suitable for loading in a `UIWebView`, `WKWebView` or passing to Safari:
Pods//GoogleSignIn/CHANGELOG.md:- Supports sign-in via UIWebView rather than app switching to a browser,

but I can't complete the solve problem.

Please Advise about this problem.

Comment: TwitterKit is archived, you shouldn't use it anymore.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is there an alternative option?

Comment: @Marcel how to solve command  this Pods//GoogleSignIn/CHANGELOG.md:- Supports sign-in via UIWebView rather than app switching to a browser,

Comment: Make sure you are using the latest version of that pod "pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 5.0'", and run pod update.